Strange ODE system
As I was solving a physics problem I came across this very strange ODE. My goal is to get the differential equation for the temperature T. The problem is that I can't get rid of the current I in any ways. Thanks
$$\begin{cases}
I=\dfrac{\alpha}{R_0}(T-T_0)-\dfrac{L}{R_0}\dfrac{dI}{dt}\\
    C\dfrac{dT}{dt}=-\alpha TI-k(T-T_0)
\end{cases}$$
I tried differentiating the equations with respect to T and t, but I couldn't solve it.
For those wondering the problem is about a Peltier cell which seats in between two bodies. The lower one is at constant temperature $T_0$, while the upper one in changing his temperature $T(t)$. The Peltier cell acts like a generator in a RL circuit with the inductance L and the inner resistance of the cell $R_0$. Maybe I'm just missing some equation.

I'm surprised at the term $\alpha TI$; it's the only one that changes when we adjust the temperature of both bodies by the same amount.

To be strange, it is !

I've solved it! Later I'll write the solution so y'all can see it. Thanks though

For the non-physicists: $I(t)$ and $T(t)$ are functions of $t$, all the other variables are just constants?

Yes, Sorry for not being clear about that

I will leave here a way to symbolically solve the question, using Mathematica. Mathematica uses Groebner basis.
equ1 = i[t] - a/r0 (T[t] - T0) + l/r0 i'[t]
equ2 = c T'[t] + a T[t] i[t] + k (T[t] - T0)
equ3 = D[equ2, t]
Eliminate[{equ1 == 0, equ2 == 0, equ3 == 0}, {i[t], i'[t]}]

giving
$$
k R_0 T_0 T(t) - k R_0 T(t)^2 + \alpha^2 T_0 T(t)^2 - \alpha^2 T(t)^3 - 
  k L T_0 T'(t) - C R_0 T(t) T'(t) + 
  C L T'(t)^2 - C L T(t) T''(t) = 0
$$

$$\begin{cases}
I=\dfrac{\alpha}{R_0}(T-T_0)-\dfrac{L}{R_0}\dfrac{dI}{dt}\\
    C\dfrac{dT}{dt}=-\alpha TI-k(T-T_0)
\end{cases}$$
The first equation is solvable by multiplying it by an integration factor:
$$I+\frac{L}{R_0}\frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{\alpha}{R_0}(T-T_0) $$
$$ \exp{\left(\dfrac{R_0}{L}t\right)}I+\frac{L}{R_0}\exp{\left(\dfrac{R_0}{L}t\right)} \frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{L}{R_0}I\exp{\left(\frac{R_0}{L}t\right)}\right]=\frac{\alpha}{R_0}\exp{\left(\frac{R_0}{L}t\right)}(T-T_0)$$
$$\implies \frac{L}{R_0}I\exp{\left(\frac{R_0}{L}t\right)}=\frac{\alpha}{R_0}\int \exp{\left(\frac{R_0}{L}t\right)}(T-T_0)dt$$
$$\implies I=\frac{\alpha}{L}\exp{\left(-\frac{R_0}{L}t\right)}\int \exp{\left(\frac{R_0}{L}t\right)}(T-T_0)dt$$
So the second one becomes
$$C\frac{dT}{dt}=-\frac{\alpha^2}{L}T\exp{\left(-\frac{R_0}{L}t\right)}\int \exp{\left(\frac{R_0}{L}t\right)}(T-T_0)dt-k(T-T_0)$$
$$\implies \frac{C}{T}\exp{\left(\frac{R_0}{L}t\right)}\frac{dT}{dt}= -\frac{\alpha^2}{L}\int \exp{\left(\frac{R_0}{L}t\right)}(T-T_0)dt-\frac{k}{T}\exp{\left(\frac{R_0}{L}t\right)}(T-T_0)$$
Let $\tau=R_0/L$. Differentiating we get
$$C\left[-\frac{e^{\tau t}}{T^2}\left(\frac{dT}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{1}{T}\left(\tau e^{\tau t} \frac{dT}{dt}+e^{\tau t}\frac{d^2T}{dt^2}\right)\right]=$$
$$=-\frac{\alpha^2}{L}e^{\tau t}(T-T_0)-k\tau e^{\tau t} -\frac{kT_0}{T^2}\frac{dT}{dt}e^{\tau t}+\frac{\tau k T_0}{T}e^{\tau t}$$
$$\implies \frac{C}{T}\left[\tau \frac{dT}{dt}+\frac{d^2T}{dt^2}-\frac{1}{T}\left(\frac{dT}{dt}\right)^2\right]=-\frac{\alpha^2}{L}T+\frac{\alpha^2}{L}T_0-k\tau  -\frac{kT_0}{T^2}\frac{dT}{dt}+\frac{\tau k T_0}{T}$$
$$\implies C\frac{d^2T}{dt^2}+C\tau \frac{dT}{dt}-\frac{C}{T}\left(\frac{dT}{dt}\right)^2+
\frac{kT_0}{T}\frac{dT}{dt}+k\tau T+\frac{\alpha^2}{L}T^2-\frac{\alpha^2}{L}T_0T-\tau k T_0=0$$
$$\boxed{C\frac{d^2T}{dt^2}+C\frac{R_0}{L} \frac{dT}{dt}-\frac{C}{T}\left(\frac{dT}{dt}\right)^2+
\frac{kT_0}{T}\frac{dT}{dt}+k\frac{R_0}{L} T+\frac{\alpha^2}{L}T^2-\frac{\alpha^2}{L}T_0T-\frac{R_0}{L} k T_0=0}$$
